# Is it possible to validate a file extension using a .bat file?

Tags: validation, batch-file, file-extension

I have a .bat file that allows to the User to enter full File name (full Path) and I`m wondering if it is possible to validate if the user is entered for example .bak file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example:

```
set /p "FullPathNameData=Please enter the full path name of backup file for YourBackup: "
for /f "delims=" %%a  in ("%FullPathNameData%") do set "Extension=%%~xa"
if /i "%Extension%"==".bak" (echo %FullPathNameData% is a BAK file) else %FullPathNameData% is NOT a BAK file
```

Comment: Well i really am new at .bat file and do not understand much of the code above.... so may be i didn`t put the question right... here it is attepmt II:
I have following peace of code:
`set /p FullPathNameData=Please enter the full path name of backup file for YourBackup:` and here the user enter a fullpathname to a backup file so i want to validate that the entered from the user is a .bak file...